# @section script executes after page load?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Is it correct that a `@section Scripts{}` loads after a page is loaded? I ask this because of the following issue:

I wanted to change a C# var (Razor) based on JS code. I kinda made this work by the following script:

```
@{ ViewData\["Title"\] = "TESTPAGINA"; var rows = 4; var organizationrows = TestProgram.GetOrganizationsInNumber(Model, rows); } 

@section Scripts{

    var rowsjs = @(rows);
    for (let i=0; i < rowsjs+1; i++) {
        if (i == rowsjs) {
            alert(i);
            @(rows += -1)
            alert(@(rows));        
        }
    }
}
```

Later in my razor file, i added the following line:

```
@{ organizationrows = TestProgram.GetOrganizationsInNumber(Model, rows);}
```

Here i expected to execute the`TestProgram.GetOrganizationsInNumber(Model, rows)`to be executed with `rows = 3` (rows-1 because of the javascript), but it did not.

Sorry for the formatting, it somehow was not able to view everything as code with just the CTRL+K command.

Comment: Razor code is executed on the server to generate HTML maybe with JS. Once this render is complete all that text is sent to the client browser.  The JS will then be executed on the browser. You cannot interleave JS and Razor execution.

Comment: @Richard Thank you for you answer. So does this mean there is no way to execute (or not execute) html/razor code based on a js var? Or could this theoretically be done with partial pages? For example: Execute this partial page when window.width >= 480?

Comment: No. The only way to have something on the server perform some action is to have the JS make an HTTP request (eg. AJAX). Note partial pages are a way of having reusable sections to razor based server rendering: they will all be run and finished before the rendered page is sent to the client,

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to change a C# var (Razor) based on JS code.

No, you cannot do that because C# object and Javascript object does not exist or alive at the same time. As you may know,  The Razor variables are "Server side variables" and they don't exist anymore after the page was sent to the "Client side" means in browser.

However, just the opposite is possible you always can assign the C# object into javascript variable. Let consider following example:

Let's assume, I have the controller action where I have assigned a value on temp data just like below:

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            TempData["FromC#TOJavascript"] = "Anything from C# To Javascript".ToString();
            return View();
        }
```

Javascript:

I can access temp data over javascript variable as following:

```
var fromCSharp = '@TempData["FromC#TOJavascript"]';
alert(JSON.stringify(fromCSharp ));
```

But if I would like to to do otherwise, it wouldn't work because C# context doesn't exist anymore which is `'@TempData["FromC#TOJavascript"]'`.

**Output:**

[image]